# if condition comparing char values not working

Tags: java

My question is regarding the code below. When i do a check for the **phone number**, even when the starting char value matches the first else-if block, it still prints out the statement within the block. For example like for a value of 6456-7895 or 8222-3333, it still triggers the elseif block even though the conditions are not met.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PhoneVerifier{
public static void main(String[]args){
    numCheck();        
}

public static void numCheck(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();

    try(Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(new File(fileName))){
        fileSc.useDelimiter("\r\n");
        while(fileSc.hasNext()){
            String check = fileSc.next();
            String check2 = check.replaceAll("-", "");
            if(check2.length() != 8){
                System.out.println("Invalid phonenum: " + check);
            }else if(check2.charAt(0) != '6'|| check2.charAt(0) != '8'|| check2.charAt(0) != '9'){
                System.out.println("Invalid starting num" + check2.charAt(0));
            }else if(!(check2.matches("\\d"))){
                System.out.println("Invalid digits ");                    
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid file name.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `check2.charAt(0) != '6'|| check2.charAt(0) != '8'|| check2.charAt(0) != '9'` will always be true, because at least two of those conditions have to be true. You mean `&&`, not `||` .

Comment: "*it still triggers the elseif block even though the conditions are not met*" -> If it executes the else if, it is because the condition **is** satisfied.

Comment: @khelwood, correct me if i'm wrong but i'm checking that the value shouldn't be any of the 3 char values, meaning its not 6 nor 8 nor 9 why is the "and" operator used and not the "or" operator?

Comment: if a == '6' then a != '8' so a != '8' is evaluated to true. so a!='6' || a!='8' is false||true so it is true

Comment: @Gabberz, you need to understand the logical operator. `||`  basicly means `1 true is needed` and `&&` means `everything need to be true`. Your condition could be reverse like `char == '6' && char == '8'` but you can't have a char with two distinct value.

Comment: @Gabberz If the character is not `'6'`, then `check2.charAt(0)!='6'` is true, so the whole expression is true. If the character *is* `'6'`, then `check2.charAt(0)!='8'` is true, so the whole expression is true. The whole expression is true whatever the value of the character.